# how to get nodejs process.arvg and above?

Tags: node.js, argument-passing

Been looking for the simplest way to capture argv[4] and any more after that?

`$ node script.js foo bar la di da`

```
var a = process.argv[2];
var b = process.argv[3];
var c = process.argv[?];
```

wanting to capture `la di da` .. was thinking `>=` or similar..? maybe `forEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to capture the remaining arguments into a single variable, then try:

```
var c = process.argv.slice(4);
```

`c` will be a variable containing the remaining CLI parameters